# Can I specify ninja.port in config file?

Tags: java, ninjaframework

Is it possible to specify the port my application will listen to in config file? I know I can use `java -Dninja.port=8765 MyNinjaApp.jar` from command line, but is it possible to do it in config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - that's currently not possible (Ninja 5.1.2).

There are ways to implement that however. Let's discuss on our mailing list if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks Raph! Sure, we can move to mailing list. There's already a topic  [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ninja-framework/llzdHpgTaXo) but if you like you can create new one where we can discuss how I (or someone else) can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

By convention Ninja will look for a configuration file at `conf/application.conf`.

File `application.conf` is a simple properties file with keys and values. To configure port:

```
serverPort=8765
```

[Take a look here](http://www.ninjaframework.org/documentation/configuration_and_modes.html)

Comment: Thanks Jordi but unfortunately it seems this is only the example of using `application.conf`. serverPort property itself does not set port in which application will listen to.

Comment: you read the link? I guess it works, but not as you expect: *First way is to use `NinjaProperties.get(…)`. **You have to inject NinjaProperties first, then you can use all sorts of functions to retrieve properties**.* Something like `String port = ninjaProperties.get("serverPort")`

Comment: I read it of course. Let's say I get the value of serverPort property in code, as you suggested. But that raises 2 new questions: 1) how can I use that value to set the port programmatically? 2) where should that be done so that it is valid before any requests are served? In controller? In module? Somewhere else?